# MPS430F2619 ADC12 channel 10

Tags: adc, msp430

I am using MSP430F2619 for data acquisition. Channel 10 of ADC12 was shown in Data sheet as temperature sensor. But also on Block diagram a Vref_x is also assigned to channel 10. How did we know if I am measuring Vref or temperature diode ?

Comment: Which block diagram are you referring to?  I'm looking at section 22.3.1 and at fig. 23-1 in the [family user guide (slau144 rev. J)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf).  The channel `1010` is for temperature sensor exclusively.

Comment: I thought it is internal ref voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 23.2.7 of the User's Guide says:

> Selecting the temperature sensor automatically turns on the on-chip reference generator as a voltage source for the temperature sensor.